# Why does the expression: If (A:=!A) evaluate differently each time a hotkey is pressed?

Tags: switch-statement, autohotkey

In an Autohotkey script, once a user presses the *CapsLock* key, a *SplashText* should pop up indicating that it is ON, or out when it is OFF, the problem here is not about the code that gets it to work but how much simpler it can get.

There are different ways that do it, some need about 25 lines, some use *SetTimer* and *GetKeyState* internal functions and several loops to get it to run, some just about five and no loops.

Simplest:

```
#SingleInstance Force
SetCapsLockState, Off


~CapsLock::
If (Tog:=!Tog)
SplashTextOn ,350 ,35 , Wanted !, [CapsLock] Activated.
else
SplashTextOff

return
```

How does: **If (Tog:=!Tog)** get this code running so easily? **Tog** is just a variable not initiated, and each time the *CapsLock* is pressed it is continuously changing its value from 1 to 0

It seems to be acting as a *Flag* in the code? what am I missing in this line:

```
If (Tog:=!Tog)
```

What makes it evaluate different each time?

This is one below is another approach with **A = 0** working as a switch, I made this one and it doesn't quite get as simple as I'd like it to be but it does the job.

Longer code:

```
#SingleInstance Force 
SetCapsLockState, Off

~CapsLock::

    If (A = 0) 
    {
    SplashTextOn ,350 ,35 , Wanted !, [CapsLock] Activated.
    A=1
        }else
        {
        SplashTextOff
        A=0
        }

return
```

Longest code:

This last one gets the same result but checks the actual physical state of the key It wouldn't rely on **SetCapsLockState, Off** at the top of the script to make sure a switch will do the rest of the work in just one line as the simpler one.

```
#SingleInstance Force
#Persistent

SetTimer, StateCapsLockON_Timer, 100
Return

~CapsLock::

StateCapsLockON_Timer
    If GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")
    {
    SetTimer, StateCapsLockOFF_Timer, 100
    SplashTextOn ,350 ,35 , Wanted !, [CapsLock] Activated.
    SetTimer, StateCapsLockON_Timer, Off
    }
 Return

StateCapsLockOFF_Timer:
    If !GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")
    {
    SetTimer, StateCapsLockOFF_Timer, Off
    SplashTextOff
    SetTimer, StateCapsLockON_Timer, On
    }
Return
```

Any good ideas about the way **If (Tog:=!Tog)** works in the simplest of these three examples?

Comment: This is really not worthy of a full answer.  The idea is very simple.  You are doing assignment to a variable `Tog := ...`   If you put an assignment inside of a logical evaluation (something) this will always evaluate to true, because the assignment will be made.  When you assign to a variable the value `Tog:=!Tog`  you can think of it as "Set Tog equal to the value of `Not Tog`.  So if Tog was True, Not Tog is false.  If Tog is False, Not Tog is true.  This is a common toggling technique across programming languages.

Comment: @gview I had the impression that the if statement was just comparing values, had not gone as far as to notice that Tog was being reassigned, thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key difference is the usage of the assignment operator `:=` as opposed to the comparing operator `=`. Since, as you've seen, you can evaluate expressions in an if-statement, you can actually include both operators in the same if-statement. Here's an example:

```
f1::
If (( test := 3+2 ) = 5 )
    MsgBox
Return
```

Here "test" is first being assigned the sum of 3+2, then compared to 5. So, the key is that if-statements allow assignments to take place and that assignments take place first, that is, before anything is compared and evaluated to be true or false.

If there is no comparing operator (= , <, >, <=, >=), as is the case in your toggle, it just evaluates whether the variable itself is true or false. If the variable is blank, 0, or false, it evaluates to false; everything else is true, even the string "false".

---

Now for the fun bit. We can actually reduce your code to one line if we use `Progress` with the "zh0" option.

```
~CapsLock::Progress , % ( Tog := !Tog ) ? "zh0 w350 h35" : "Off" ,, [CapsLock] Activated. , Wanted !
```

Unfortunately, this isn't possible with `SplashText` since these are actually two separate commands. But the upside is that `Progress` actually has a lot more options available, so you can change the font size and color, etc.

Comment: I'm giving this `Progress` command a try this next week, the _Ternaric Operator_ seems like a really good idea here

Answer (score 1):

I got this now, check logical-not on this link:

https://lexikos.github.io/v2/docs/Variables.htm

If the operand (In this case **Tog**) is blank or 0, the result of applying logical-not (or **!Tog**) is 1, which means "true". Otherwise, the result is 0 (false)

```
if (Tog = 0)
  Tog = 1
```

would bring the same result as:

```
If Tog:=!Tog
```

Because an operation was taking place before the **If** even checked the changed value, *if* wasn't just comparing data, the operation was happening before the *if* since the values inside the parenthesis were not just being read but were also being changed and the variable being reassigned.

*(expression)* Any sub-expression enclosed in parentheses. For example, (3 + 2) * 2 forces 3 + 2 to be evaluated first.